# Conjugate a verb when you don't know the subject's quantity

Tags: verbs

I'm writing a translation for a website and I don't know how to write a sentence when I don't know the subject's quantity. In the examples below, [quantity] is an unknown variable, it can be "one" or "two" and I can only write one sentence for these two cases.

So, should I write:

> [quantity] item(s) has-have been found

or

> [quantity] item(s) has/have been found

or something else I don't know?

Thank you in advance.

Update: I'm an intern translating an existing website with strict orders from my superiors, I would have handle the translation differently if I could but it is not possible. Anyway, thank you for your answers!

Comment: Since all you have to do is check for *[quantity] = **1***, many programmers go to the trouble of altering the form of the noun that follows (Google Books, for example, says *1 **result** found*, but it's ***results** found* for all other values. You should copy them and just don't bother with the unnecessary verb *has/have*. If for some reason you can only use one fixed format text string, I wouldn't bother with any of it - just use ***[n] items found*** for all values of ***n***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: At least it's simple as long as you *only* need to do it in English. Once you start really internationalizing your software, [it](http://localization-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html) [gets](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html) [fun](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html).

Comment: @Ilmari: Haha - that takes me back! 30 years ago I thought I was "leading edge" because I used things like **printf ("%d file%s deleted", n, n == 1 ? "" : "s");** (back when every last byte was precious! :) 10 years after *that* I wrote a system where the users had to maintain their own table for every language they wanted, so it became **printf ("%d %s",n, usr_txt_files_deleted);** As implied by my first comment, I never really bothered with the singular/plural issue after that. But it was an interesting diversion at the time, so thanks for the trip down memory lane! <sigh>

Comment: As the various coding and/or rewriting solutions illustrate, this is a well-known issue and the best answer is usually to avoid the problem.

Comment: Honestly, the problem is that English clearly needs a good refactoring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you can't do it correctly, you might try something like this instead:

> [quantity] item(s) found

Deleting the perfect and passive auxiliaries means you no longer have a finite verb, which means the verb doesn't have to change form to agree with the subject.  This is much preferable to writing *has/have* everywhere.

This isn't Standard English grammar, but it's probably fine in a user interface.  People are used to seeing things like this on computers and in other situations where space is at a premium.  In particular, a similar reduced grammar called **headlinese** is often used in headlines.

The parentheses are a little clunky, but if you don't include them you'll end up saying "1 items found" when there's only one result, and this is undesirable.  Since it's a compromise either way, it's up to you whether you want to include them or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just for curiosity: when you have two possible choices in a sentence, do you write ... a/b... or ...a-b...? E.g. "his/her" or "his-her"?

Comment: A forward slash would be preferable (A/B), but even better is not to present two alternatives in that manner.

Comment: Also, using "their" is acceptable as a gender neutral possessive determiner, as opposed to "his/her", and "they" as opposed to "he/she".

Answer (score 4):

Could you not try this?

> Total items found: [quantity]